# Creating Tables using VBA with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have following table:

"Censors Market Value"

Column A   -Type
Type 1
Type 2
Type 3

Column B   -Country
US
Canada
Mexico

I want to create a table for "US Censors value by type"

"US Censors value by type"

Column A  -Type
Type 1
Type 2
Type 3

Column B   -Year
XX
XX
XX

Same as for Canada and Mexico countries

I am new to VB and please suggest on this.

Comment: Pivot table would really suit your needs.

Comment: I want one table for each country with all types in column A and Column B should be blank. Also I need to generate this with the heading "Country Censors Valu by type"

Comment: Should we be assuming Excel as the host application for this "table"?